# Problema com BottonNavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vocês podem ver galera estou com um probleminha de layout nesse form no Android, este form é aberto dentro de um fragment normalmente onde eu vou realizar o envio desses dados.

1- Pra minha surpresa o `EditText` não se expande pra tela toda. Já tentei usar o LayoutParams setando matchparent mas nada aconteceu...

2- os Botões estão se escondendo atras do `BottonNavigationView`, já tentei colocar um `scrollview` ali mas ele não sai dali...

Este componente `BottonNavigation` tem que ficar fixo na tela por que eu não quero que ele se esconda com a função Behavior...como acontece aqui [BottonNavigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)

Alguém teria alguma dica pra tentar encaixar este form corretamente ou alguma ajuda do além ?

Este layout está aqui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layouparams"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nome Ex.: Pedro Silva"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email Ex.: meumail@mail.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />


        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_datanasc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Data Nasc Ex.: 01/01/1980"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10"

            app:mask="##/##/####" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_contato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Contato Ex.: (16)9999-00-99"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="14"

            app:mask="(##)####-##-##" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_rg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Rg Ex.: 000000000111"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_cpf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="CPF Ex.: 000-000-000.00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="15"

            app:mask="###-###-####.##" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Endereço Ex.: rua joao paulo 1000"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_cep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="CEP Ex.: 14600-000"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="9"

            app:mask="#####-###" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_bairro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Bairro Ex.: centro"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="9"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_cidade"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Cidade Ex.: Parnaíba-PI"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_duvidas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Dúvidas sobre o curso"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancelar" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Enviar Inscrição" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual o seu **root layout**, mas se for um **RelativeLayout** você pode utilizar o atributo `android:layout_above="@+id/idDoBottomNav"`.

O root layout é aquele que é o responsável por guardar a view do seu **Fragment**, a sua **Toolbar** e o **BottomNavigationView**.

Com constraintLayout você deve atentar-se aos atributos dele, não do RelativeLayout. O above aqui não funciona e deve ser utilizado o `constraintBottom_toTopOf` que tem a mesma função do above.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.pauloceami.ateliermaisprojetos.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containnersFragments"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

O problema aqui é que a **View** responsável por exibir o **Fragment** ocupa toda a tela e fica por baixo do **BottomNavigationView**.

Você utilizou um scroll, mas não resolveu pois o **scroll** "acredita" que já não há mais nada pra ser exibido. Isto pode ser corrigido utilizando a seguinte abordagem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layouparams"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_nome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nome Ex.: Pedro Silva"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email Ex.: meumail@mail.com"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />


        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_datanasc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Data Nasc Ex.: 01/01/1980"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10"

            app:mask="##/##/####" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_contato"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Contato Ex.: (16)9999-00-99"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="14"

            app:mask="(##)####-##-##" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_rg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Rg Ex.: 000000000111"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_cpf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="CPF Ex.: 000-000-000.00"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="15"

            app:mask="###-###-####.##" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Endereço Ex.: rua joao paulo 1000"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_cep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="CEP Ex.: 14600-000"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="9"

            app:mask="#####-###" />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_bairro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Bairro Ex.: centro"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="9"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_cidade"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Cidade Ex.: Parnaíba-PI"
            android:inputType="text"
            />

        <com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_txt_duvidas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Dúvidas sobre o curso"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Cancelar" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Enviar Inscrição" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Apenas veja que no final do teu layout eu adicionei o elemento [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) que tem essa função de dar um "espaço" entre **views**. O atributo **height** eu usei o da **ActionBar** porque provavelmente o **BottomNav** utiliza o mesmo valor ou algo próximo.

Com isto teu **layout** vai ser mostrado corretamente e não será "engolido" pelo **BottomNav**.

---

**Observação**: recomendo o uso da abordagem com o **Space**, pois parece-me mais limpa.

**Observação 2**: a abordagem com o Space permite que o usuário possa utilizar o Scroller normalmente e ver o botão. A primeira também, mas o botão não irá mais aparentar estar abaixo do BottomNav, mas sim estar sendo "cortado" por ele.

Comment: Valeu pela dica vou testar... o outro problema voce imagina o que pode ser ? digo aquele espaço na direita da tela

Comment: Não deu certo ... Testei no celular api 16 com android 4.1 nem apareceu nada na tela..as views sumiram...depois tirei e elas voltaram..... muito estranho este comportamento.

Comment: esse tal de above ai tb nao funcionou

Comment: O above não vai funcionar porque teu root layout é um constraint layout, não um relative layout. Quando for fazer uma pergunta, deixe-a completa.

Comment: @PauloCeami editei o código com o teu layout, dá uma olhada aí ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: SCREEM]

conforme estou mostrando o primeiro problema foi resolvido com o space mas nao funcionava com o attr talvez seja questao de versao etc etc... mas foi resolvido quando coloquei um valor de 50dp no height...

O segundo problema ainda esta quebrando minha cabeça... ja criei outro layout pelo android studio pra certetificar de que talvez eu pudesse estar fazendo algo errado, mas não... ele continua aparecendo essa margem no android 4 e no 6 tb... será que pode ser algum problema com o fragment ? vejam meus layouts ...

[layout com o FrameLayout](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c93fa0a5e758bb6087a8498784915cda)

[form com EditText](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ae83ee01c8065840c7966072aab284fb)

Comment: Essa problema com o espaço que apareceu eu resolvi lá na minha resposta, dá uma olhada no primeiro código, que é dó layout principal.